# Help to Fix My Computer

Tags: mac

How do I fix my Mac? Okay so I'm in a weird spot with my Mac. It has no startup up disk.  I have the installation disk for it but my super drive does not work.  I'm wondering can I boot it from a USB?  I do not care if it uses apples software or Linux.  I just want to get it to work so icon access the internet.

I have access to window computers and Mac computers if that helps.  I can download things and everything but terminal is not accessible.  If you need further info just ask.

JUST TO RECAP:

- Doesn't have Startup disk

  - So I can't go on it to do things
- I don't care if it runs Linux or Apple

  - NOT WINDOWS
- I have access to windows and Mac computers

  - BUT they don't have full access
- Can load things to my USB
- I don't care if I need to get a few things for it to work
- Request more info if needed

Thank you in advance if you find anything help full

Comment: Use the Target Disk mode (from a second Mac)

Comment: You can create a bootable Linux USB stick (e.g. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/).

Comment: please add the model identifiers of your Macs to your question. (Terminal command: system_profiler | grep "Model Identifier")

Answer (score 1):

What "Doesn't work" about your superdrive? Is it possible to get another USB Disk Drive?

I'm assuming that since you don't have "full" access to the other Macs that the Disk Utility app on them is inaccessible to you as well. Check on that, if you can. IF you can get into Disk Utility on one of the other Macs, you might be able to connect the two using a Firewire or Thunderbolt cable and go into Target Disk Mode to [restore your Mac.](http://www.prosofteng.com/blog/using-target-disk-mode-to-recover-macintosh-hard-drive/)

Another option would be to use the Terminal to create your own bootable USB drive. Even if its your buddy's MacBook, you should still be able to log into the App Store, download the installer for whatever version you bought, and use the built-in `createinstallmedia` to make a [bootable drive](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5856).

If both of these options don't work, I think your next best bet is to buy an install disk off eBay or something. Hardly ideal, but then at least you'd have them if this happens again.

Comment: nice work, you get a +1 from me for that.

Answer (score 0):

Wow thats a hum dinger of a problem.

From what I understand you only have terminal access to both mac and linux.

Below are the directions for both linux and mac

For your linux machine you will need to install x11 and firefox if they are not already installed. If you have ownership rights and are using apt as your package manager type sudo apt-get install firefox x11. For other package managers on linux you will have to consult someone else. I only have experience with apt. If you don't have ownership rights you will have to install firefox and x11 locally by downloading the source and compiling them. Firefox can be downloaded from the terminal using Firefox's FTP server. I have no idea how to get the x11 source for linux. Realistically unless the machine you are working on is a cluster you should have these software already installed even if no GUI is present.

After the installation type firefox in the terminal. Go to the linux distro webpage and download the os onto your USB.

For mac osx you have a multitude of options. If you want a linux distro, you can type open -a Safari or open -a Firefox to open the Safari or Firefox apts. Than go to linux distro's website and download the os to USb. If you want a OS X distro type open -a Software\ Update. Download a copy of the OS X distro than use the terminal to copy the distro unto the USB. By the way each version of OS X has a different terminal command for copying OS X onto a USB or DVD. So you'll have to look up this command.

Once you have your OS on your USB plug in to the computer and install.